# Reduce number of displayed edges in EdgeDetect

Tags: plotting, image-processing

```
EdgeDetect[
      Import["https://twistedsifter.files.wordpress.com/2016/10/perfect_\
    camellia_flower_close_up.jpg?w=800"]] // ColorNegate
```

I would like to reduce the number of edges displayed in EdgeDetect. How can I do it ?

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Check the second attribute of `EdgeDetect`. `EdgeDetect[img, 3] // ColorNegate ` seems to have reduced the number of edges. Is this what you want?

Comment: Could you explain more precisely why you mean by _reducing the number of displayed edges_?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to approach this kind of thing is to preprocess the image. In this case, an edge preserving smoothing function might be useful:

```
img=Import["https://twistedsifter.files.wordpress.com/2016/10/perfect_camellia_flower_close_up.jpg?w=800"];
EdgeDetect[MeanShiftFilter[img, 3, 0.5]] // ColorNegate
```

[image]

The parameters of the filter (here 3 and 0.5) change the number of edges detected.